# Transferring data from gcloud vm instance in one google account to GCS in a different google account

Tags: machine-learning, gcloud

The title says it all. I have a VM instance set up in my google cloud for generating some model data. A friend of mine also has a new account. We're both basically using the free credits Google provides. We're trying to figure out if there is a way that I can generate the data in my VM instance and then transfer it to my friend's GCS Bucket. He hasn't set up any buckets yet, so we're also open to suggestions on the type of storage that would help us do this task.

I realize I can set up a persistent disk and mount it to my own VM instance. But that isn't our goal right now. We just need to know if there is a way to transfer data from one Google account to another. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, your question is not showing much about what you have researched so far - it's pretty light on.  Try fleshing it out with a little more detail about what you have attempted and what you are trying to achieve as an outcome.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this by having your friend create the bucket and then he gives your email permission to access the bucket. Then from your VM you can us the gsutil command to copy the files to the bucket.

1) Have your friend create the bucket in the console.
2) In the [permissions section](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-iam), he will Add Member and add your email and provide you with [Storage Object Creator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#storage-roles) role
3) Then you SSH into your VM and use the following [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) command to copy the files. For example `gsutil cp testfile.txt gs://friend_bucket`
4) If you get 403 error, you probably have to run `gcloud auth login` first